# Insert a field with value whenever new instance of modal is created

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to insert a field with value whenever new row is created for a modal.

Ex:  Suppose this is my user.php modal

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
 protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

What i want is in my application anywhere when i insert a row in user table, then i want to insert an extra column `code` with its value in user table.

Ex: If i do below in my application

```
User::create(['name'=>'xyz', 'password' => 'kajsndjk']);
```

then it should insert an extra column `code =>'Qwedf'` also in my table.

In my application there are many places where i am creating the users, so i don't want to remember every time to insert `code` column.

Please suggest how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the static `create` function on the `User` class is the only thing that will work in my opinion.

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
   $object = parent::create($attributes);
   $object->code = 'some text';
   $object->save();

   return $object;
}
```

I've tested and like I expected, oseintow's answer will not work, because it would work *only* if you directly modified `code` variable, which you obviously are not doing.

Comment: Your answer was correct, you were just missed to call `save()` on `$object`. I have edited the answer Thanks for the answer :).

Comment: You are right, create should also save the object. Thanks for the edit! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this mutator to your User model

```
public function setCodeAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['code'] = "Qwedf";
}
```

Anytime you are saving a record code will be assigned the Qwedf value